# "Quick Fluid" is reflecting an old (not current) HDRI

Tags: fluid-simulation, hdri, reflection

The environment texture with a tree (shown in reflection) was not the world texture set when I created the "Quick Fluid" it was the stars.

I can't work out, how this old texture is being reflected, there are hardly any objects in the scene.  I've deleted and recreated the "Quick fluid" but it's always showing this old texture with the tree, and not the stars.

[image: Reflection showing different HDRI]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Hello :). Is the wrong reflection shown in viewport or also in render? This looks like one of the default viewport HDRIs.

Comment: You call it "old texture", do you refer to it as an actual texture you've used in the past or why? Because you said you created the fluid with the starry background. I guess @JachymMichal is right, it looks like the default viewport HDRI. It would be good if you provided information if this is _Material Preview_ or _Rendered View_ for example.

Comment: I'd used one with a tree in the past, but maybe I've made a bad assumption, maybe it is just some default.

How can I get it to reflect with the stars hdri?

Comment: In the _Viewport Shading_ options (the dropdown menu next to the shading type buttons), enable _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_.